IK Legs: Pole Rotate in Circle
I am making IK for legs. I have a target bone and a pole bone. I want the knee to always face the same direction as the foot. So whenever I rotate the target (foot rotates), and therefore should also the pole bone, but in circle.
For better understanding here is a picture of what I want to achieve:

Currently the pole just copies rotation of target, but I also want it to move, so it is in front of the foot.
Does anyone know how to do this?
